# Custom command line editor in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, zsh, ansi-term

I would like to invoke my own command line editor in `bash` or `zsh` when `Alt+Enter` is being pressed. It should do some editing and submit result to the shell on `Enter`. So basically my editor takes current command line content and returns a modified one. Any ideas how to approach integration? I do know how to work with ANSI terminals, just wondering how to integrate my editor console app to the shell in this way.

Comment: The bash builtin `bind` should give you everything you need.  But it seems that (using vi key bindings), `v` pretty much does what you want, opening the current command line in $EDITOR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bash:

There is a Readline command that opens the current command in an editor, [`edit-and-execute-command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-edit_002dand_002dexecute_002dcommand-_0028C_002dx-C_002de_0029). By default, it is bound to `C-x C-e`, and it opens the command in what `$VISUAL` is set to, or `$EDITOR`, or with Emacs.

You can set `$VISUAL` to your editor by exporting it into the environment, for example in `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
export VISUAL=youreditor
```

and bind it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> with

```sh
bind '"\e\C-m": edit-and-execute-command'
```

on the command line, or

```sh
"\e\C-m": edit-and-execute-command
```

in `~/.inputrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same for zsh:

```
  export VISUAL=youreditor
  autoload -Uz edit-command-line
  zle -N edit-command-line
  bindkey '\e\C-m' edit-command-line
```